# Most complexity optimized way to define a 2D array using Numpy, Custom defined user functions, and Lambda Operators

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory, vectorization

- I have a question on how one can define a Vectorized Numpy type array but in 2 dimensions using a combination of Lambda functions, Numpy user defined function definition.
- For the sake of complexity, I am trying to basically completely eliminate for loops and replace it by User defined numpy functions coupled with Lambda operators.
- This is the statement that works for me when not vectorized through numpy definition.

  ```
  data3= [[func(element, L2, d2, slit_width, small_delta, lamda, N2, intensity_scaling, 'false', elemental) for element in posrange3] for elemental in posrange3b]
  ```
- where element and elemental are counters for the 2d array and everything else are constants or variables
- I would like to write something like this but in multiple dimensions (2 or 3). I am currently able to do this only for 1 dimension (2 without nesting so effectively 1) as shown below.

  ```
  data3=np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: func(j, L, d, slit_width, small_delta, lamda, N, intensity_scaling, 'true', i), (len(posrange2), len(posrange2b)), dtype=np.float)
  ```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: `lambda` is just a different syntax fro defining a Python function.  Functionally there's nothing special about them.

Comment: `lambda` does not help performance. This is true with regular Python code, but it is especially the case for NumPy.

Comment: Read the code for `fromfunction`.  It probably is not doing what you think.   It calls your function once, using arrays created by `np.indices`.  If your func can only take scalar `i,j` values it does not help.

Comment: As long as `func` is a 'black-box' that only takes scalar values, we can't help you. You have to call it once for each `i,j` pair of indices.  Calling that many times is the main time consumer.

Comment: Aah, I see. That's helpful. Seems like there is no way to do a 2D array directly from np.fromfunction without nesting them with a for loop then.

Comment: @shantanuk100 well, no, you could re-shape it. But in any case, `np.fromfunction` is mostly a convenience, it's not really going to be more performant than your list-comprehension approach, I'd bet. Although, maybe if space is an issue it could be advantageous in that regard\

Comment: Aah I see. I assumed that since everything in np is intrinsically vectorized the fromfunction would also be run through C in the background and prove faster that regular python based list comprehension.